Web application having database with OPC client
I'm designing a browser-based application that will display real-time data collected from OPC server. I have decided to use Angular framework for the browser application development. The browser application will have feature where user will enter tag names (or node id) that will be stored as record in MySQL DB. As data is to be collected and displayed on the browser application from OPC server, there is a need to have an OPC client. The OPC client will basically read all those tag names and passed onto OPC server for the latter to return values. Those values will also be stored as records in the MySQL DB to be queried and displayed on the browser. Furthermore, the control of the OPC client (i.e. enabling or disabling it) will be triggered from the browser application.
I have a question with regards to the OPC client. Is it appropriate to develop the OPC client separately (i.e. develop as an executable and configure it as a Windows Service) or incorporate the OPC client code within the browser application code?
Your view is very much appreciated.

I have no experience at all with OPC, but from its description it sounds like you would need to implement a separate OPC client that provides some kind of HTTP API for use by the web application.

What are your requirements as far as authentication and authorization? I think going with a pure web solution is ideal if you can get away with it and it looks like OPC can work off of HTTP/SOAP. A separate service is almost always a big hassle and you can do a ton of stuff with just client JS these days.

@Dyllon Gagnier. As far as my knowledge goes with OPC authentication is that both client and server must have the same account configured. I'm not familiar with authorization though. I just found out that NodeJS have node-opc package that can be install and the OPC client can be coded within typescript. I'm contemplating your suggestion of going in this direction.
